# Storing path in config file

Tags: bash, macos, variables, path, special-characters

In a macOS environment all characters except for `:` and ASCII control characters can be used in a filename. We are making a configuration file for a shell script and need it to use the path specified, taking into consideration that paths/filenames can consist of possibly confusing characters.

However, we are not sure if we should make the user automatically escape every impoprtant character (, `/`, `$` etc.) or if there is a better way for this (the former is extremely inconvenient. A file or folder named `tips/tricks` is called `tips:tricks` in Terminal and used the same way.

What we are looking for is if there are any specific methods/correct ways of storing paths in bash variables to prevent accidental interpretation of other files or folders (like a folder called `me/you` is specified that way in configuration file and the folder `me`/`you` is followed instead).

We are also looking for what would be most user friendly.

P.S. our configuration is a plain txt file (says `usedpath=USERINPUTHERE`)

Comment: Forget about user-friendly, end user doesn't know what he wants. Allow only alphanumeric characters, space, dash and underscore, and prohibit filenames starting with a dash, then everything will be neat

Comment: Please explain exactly how you think you'd end up with a file or folder with a forward slash in the name on macOS.

Comment: @JosephSible https://imgur.com/a/fvhgzJa

Comment: @leetbacoon Finder is lying to you. That file is really called `me:you.txt`.

Comment: @leetbacoon Ah, I see the problem. You think `:` is the only thing not allowed in names, and that Terminal escapes `/` as `:`. That's backwards. It's really `/` that's not allowed in names, and Finder escapes `:` as `/`.

Comment: @JosephSible Yes, but still, how is this stored easily and reliably in the config file? That is what I am wondering. But thanks for clarifying that

Comment: @leetbacoon the file may have [utf8 slash character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2215) not slash `0x2f` character. On my terminal they look exactly identical. Try `echo '∕ /' | hexdump -C`. Or maybe more evil `touch 'abc∕def.txt'`

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, but if its kept in home folder what if username/home folder is `ヒロ/けん`?

Comment: @KamilCuk It is 0x2f, I checked by creating a folder with division slash and regular slash.  Regular slash appears as `:` where other appears as `∕`

Comment: `how is this stored easily and reliably` - the most reliable and worst user friendly way - convert everything with `xxd -p` to hex string. [Och my](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/677339) I see you can use slash in filenames on macos.

Comment: @KamilCuk Lol okay just most reliable is what am looking for